# Powershell how to check if text file is empty and ignore whitespaces

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to make a simple check for a log file if it's empty or not

```
if (Get-Content path-to-file) {
  do stuff
}
```

Issue is that the file may contain a white-space only and return true
I tried `.replace(" ", "")` and `.trim()` still returns true, what can I do?

Comment: try something like the following to make an array of spaces and/or empty strings into an empty array ... `@(' ', '', '   ').Where({-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)})`

Answer (score 2):

Found a fix if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($logContent)) {
do stuff
}

Comment: You may find `if(Get-Content path\to\file -TotalCount 1){ ... }` to be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary to read all file with get-content (be carefull to performance if you test a big file), try this :

```
if ((get-item "c:\temp\test.txt").Length -gt 0)
{
  "File is not empty"
}
else
{
  "File is empty"
}
```

Comment: This however reports files with just whitespace(s) in them as 'not empty', where the OP wants those files to be regarded empty aswell..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$log = Get-Content -Path '.\Desktop\Document.txt'

if ((($null -eq $log) -or ($log.Trim().Length -eq 0))) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

The null check must be first as in case the file is empty it would otherwise throw an error. In this situation, if `$log` is empty, the second check will be skipped automatically.